# Avoiding splitting the subject and verb with a long explanation

Tags: grammaticality

I want to avoid an expression of the form `the probability that blah blah blah blah blah would increase.`    The greater the number of blah's, the more awkward this construction becomes.     Is it syntactically acceptable to say `the probability would increase that blah blah blah blah blah.`?   While this second construction sounds a bit funny, it seems clearer to me than hanging the "would increase" out at the end of the sentence.

Comment: The second construction is syntactically acceptable. But you might also consider rewording the previous sentence so you could say something like: *This would increase the probability that blah blah blah ...*

Comment: Please accept, "avoiding splitting the subject and verb with a long explanation" could never matter; neither grammatically nor semantically.

It might matter what you meant by “I want to avoid an expression of the probability that blah blah blah blah blah would increase”, for the simple reason that other than your ideas about that particular “blah lah…” there is what?

Comment: Or: *the probability that there would be an increase in blah blah blah blah blah blah*. (It's difficult to be more precise since you haven't given a complete sentence.)

Comment: Thanks, all, I went with a variant of @Peter_Shor's suggestion.   My final choice:   "There will be an increase in the probability that ..."      Both this and Peter's suggestion are much better than my original     Completely obvious ex post, can't think why I didn't think of either of them initially.